# Quickbooks unrecoverable error pro 2012

Tags: quickbooks

If I leave Quickbooks open long enough it eventually will crash up to where you have to restart it a few times. Ideas? Here is one of the errors:

```
quickbooks unrecoverable error pro 2012 00000 19101
```

Answer (score 0):

Google search with `site:intuit.com YOUR PROBLEM OR QUESTION` is highly useful.

https://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Articles/SLN41065 has an answer, which I found by searching in google with the string `site:intuit.com Unrecoverable Error`. 
[Make sure UAC is enabled](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7), by

1. Click the Windows Start button, and then click Control Panel.
2. If it is not already selected, click Classic View in the left side
   of the window.
3. Double-click User Accounts.
4. Click Turn User Account Control on or off.
5. Make sure Use User Account Control (UAC) is set on.

If that does not resolve the issue, restart QuickBooks with no company file open, by holding down the Alt key (release only to password in).

Once you open the company file, then do File | Back Up Company | Local Backup and make sure Complete Verification is enabled.  If a data error is found, re-backup the file after turning off Complete Verification, and then use the ten pages of the [Data Damage instructions](https://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Articles/HOW20804) to repair the file.

If you are not able to open a company file normally, make sure the file is on your local C: drive, for double-clicking on a network file location to open it is iffy.

If problems persist, and the file is local, copy it to another directory and retry. Should that fail, close QuickBooks again, and restart QuickBooks by itself by holding down the Ctrl key, click on the program's icon, and continue to until you reach the No Company Open screen. Then, single click on the file, and then click on the OPEN button.